# Javascript Refactoring, Following DRY method - How would you clone options passed into a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, javascript-objects, dry

Since I'm trying to follow the DRY pattern, how would someone do something like this? (but the correct way)?

```
const lazyObj = {
  bind: 'event',
  effect: 'fadeIn',
  effectTime: 500,
  threshold: 0
}

$('.js-lazy, .js-lazy-homepage').lazy(lazyObj);

$('.js-other-lazy').lazy({
  ...lazyObj,
  beforeLoad: function() {
    $('.js-skeleton').hide();
  }
})
```

Essentially would want to rewrite this:

```
$('.js-lazy, .js-lazy-homepage').lazy({
  bind: 'event',
  effect: 'fadeIn',
  effectTime: 500,
  threshold: 0
});

$('.js-other-lazy').lazy({
  bind: 'event',
  effect: 'fadeIn',
  effectTime: 500,
  threshold: 0,
  beforeLoad: function() {
    $('.js-skeleton').hide();
  }
})
```

Since I'm using the same values:

```
{
  bind: 'event',
  effect: 'fadeIn',
  effectTime: 500,
  threshold: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend and object into another.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend

```js
var primary = {
  bind: 'event',
  effect: 'fadeIn',
  effectTime: 500,
  threshold: 0
};

var secondary = jQuery.extend(
  { beforeLoad: function() { $('.js-skeleton').hide(); } },
  primary
);

console.log(primary);
console.log(secondary);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```